# Пользователь уровня базы данных

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

У меня на экземпляре SQL Server 2012 зарегистрированно два пользователя: `ape` и `ais2015`. Оба пользователя уровня сервера. `ape` у меня как администраторская учетка, а `ais2015` для пользователя (работает только в режиме для чтения).

Мне необходимо ограничить для `ais2015` доступ к таблице `coko.or_user`.

1. Какая разница между типом пользователя `Пользователь SQL без имени входа` и `Пользователь SQL c именем пользователя` ? Как вообще используется первый вариант, ведь с помощью него даже нельзя авторизоваться с помощью SQL Server Management Studio.
2. Я попытался ограничить доступ к таблице `or_user` для пользователя `ais2015` командами

> ```
> REVOKE SELECT ON coko.or_user TO ais2015
> DENY DELETE ON coko.or_user TO ais2015
> ```

но все равно `ais2015` имеет доступ к `or_user`. Видимо потому что эта учетка уровня сервера. Неважно что будет с `ais2015`, но как мне создать пользователя, который имел бы доступ ко всем таблицам базы coko кроме таблицы `or_user`?

Comment: вы что-то тут путаете , есть логины и есть пользователи базы и это разные сущности.

Comment: @Konst  т.е. если я правильно понимаю, то у меня выходит 2 `логина` (ape и ais2015) и 2 `пользователя`,  имена которых совпадают с названиями логинов (ape и ais2015). Так?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что касается второго пункта, то возможно дело в `REVOKE SELECT`. `REVOKE` снимает разрешение, выданное ранее с помощью `GRANT` (либо запрещение, установленное с помощью `DENY`). Если разрешение/запрещение не делалось, то команда исполняется, но эффекта не имеет. Если для доступа к объекту разрешение не было выдано ранее с помощью `GRANT`, то для запрещения вместо `REVOKE` следует использовать `DENY`. Также своим `REVOKE SELECT` вы могли снять запрещение, если оно было установлено, сделав доступной выборку из таблицы.

Если делать с нуля, то для достижения того, что вы хотите, у вас должно быть примерно следующее.

Создаём логин для доступа к серверу и пользователя БД, связанного с этим логином:

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [TestLogin] WITH PASSWORD=N'123'
GO
USE [DbName]
GO
CREATE USER [DbUser] FOR LOGIN [TestLogin]
GO
```

Замечу, что в данном случае имя пользователя БД не совпадает с именем логина к серверу, но они могут и совпадать (кстати, если создавать логин через диалог в SSMS и делать ему mapping в пользователя БД, то по-умолчанию так и происходит, в связи с чем может возникнуть путаница).

Теперь разрешим пользователю чтение данных, но запретим его для выбранного объекта:

```
USE [DbName]
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [DbUser]
GO
DENY SELECT ON [coko].[or_user] TO [DbUser]
GO
```

Также, если требуется, разрешим изменения данных, но запретим их для выбранного объекта:

```
ALTER ROLE [db_datawriter] ADD MEMBER [DbUser]
GO
DENY UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON [coko].[or_user] TO [DbUser]
GO
```

---

Что касается первого пункта (пользователи БД без логина):

```
USE [Test]
GO
CREATE USER [LoginlessUser] WITHOUT LOGIN
GO
```

то такие пользователи часто используются для имперсонализации, т.е. выполнения действий кем-то другим от имени такого пользователя.

К примеру, можно создать процедуру, которая будет исполняться от имени определённого пользователя и делать что-то, что доступно лишь этому пользователю:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DoSomething
WITH EXECUTE AS 'LoginlessUser'
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- делаем что-то, что доступно LoginlessUser
END
```

Другим пользователям можно дать права на исполнение этой процедуры.

Также можно переключать контекст исполнения, для того, чтобы выполнять команды от имени кого-то:

```
-- сменим контекст
EXECUTE AS USER = 'LoginlessUser';
GO
-- делаем что-то от имени LoginlessUser
GO
-- вернёмся в свой контекст
REVERT;
GO
```